# plotly: Highlight / identify certain countries in choropleth

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have the following choropleth in Python:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
countries = ['BDI', 'BEN', 'BFA', 'BWA', 'CIV', 'CMR', 'COD', 'CPV', 'ETH', 'GHA', 'GIN', 'GMB', 'KEN', 'LBR', 'LSO', 'MDG', 'MLI', 'MOZ', 'MUS', 'MWI', 'NER', 'NGA', 'RWA', 'SEN', 'SLE', 'SOM', 'STP', 'TCD', 'TGO', 'TZA', 'UGA', 'ZAF', 'ZMB', 'ZWE']
z = [5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 14, 7, 1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 13, 1, 3, 11, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 50, 18, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 16, 15, 4, 10, 4]
layout = dict(geo={'scope': 'africa'})
data = dict(
    type='choropleth',
    locations=countries,
    locationmode='ISO-3',
    colorscale='Viridis',
    z=z)
map = go.Figure(data=[data], layout=layout)
py.plot(map)
```

I would like to highlight some countries into 1 of 2 categories, let's say priority levels. Some are priority 1, some priority 2, and some non-priority. This priority level is not related to the corresponding `z` value in the plot.

In the plot I would like to visually distinguish the two priority levels from each other and from the non-priority countries which should remain formatted in the default way. All should fit under the same colour scale though.

This could be by changing the shading texture of those countries, e.g. diagonal hatches. Or by having a distinctive outline, e.g. thicker, different colour, or dashed lines.

Apologies for not being very specific about the required output, I am unsure about the capabilities of plotly and it's the outcome of making some countries stand out, irrespective of their plot value, that's important. I'm open to any methods people have used before for this kind of thing!

Thanks

Comment: I see the requirements for the question have been modified. I could have responded more quickly if you had commented on the response.

Comment: @r-beginners , no modification, just a clarification of something that was mentioned below already. Just working on your answer in my code so will respond there soon! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced in this either, but I would suggest two approaches.

1. define the boundaries of the country.
2. customize the `colorscalse`.

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
countries = ['BDI', 'BEN', 'BFA', 'BWA', 'CIV', 'CMR', 'COD', 'CPV', 'ETH', 'GHA', 'GIN', 'GMB', 'KEN', 'LBR', 'LSO', 'MDG', 'MLI', 'MOZ', 'MUS', 'MWI', 'NER', 'NGA', 'RWA', 'SEN', 'SLE', 'SOM', 'STP', 'TCD', 'TGO', 'TZA', 'UGA', 'ZAF', 'ZMB', 'ZWE']
z = [5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 14, 7, 1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 13, 1, 3, 11, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 50, 18, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 16, 15, 4, 10, 4]
layout = dict(geo={'scope': 'africa'})
# colorscalec customize
scl = [[0.0, 'rgb(242,240,247)'],[0.2, 'rgb(218,218,235)'],[0.4, 'rgb(188,189,220)'],\
            [0.6, 'rgb(158,154,200)'],[0.8, 'rgb(117,107,177)'],[1.0, 'rgb(84,39,143)']]

data = dict(
    type='choropleth',
    locations=countries,
    locationmode='ISO-3',
    colorscale=scl,
    autocolorscale = False,
    marker = dict(line = dict (color = 'rgb(255,255,255)', width = 2)),
    z=z)
map = go.Figure(data=[data], layout=layout)
py.plot(map)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @r-beginners , thanks a lot for taking the time to respond. This wasn't quite what I was looking for. It was about distinguishing different countries within the group of countries with data. Your response lead to my solution however, posted here, which was to add a different trace for each group, and having a different outline colour. Cheers!

Comment: I wasn't able to answer all of your questions, but I'm glad your goal was realized.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, going forward from @r-beginners, was to have a separate trace for each priority group, each with a different coloured outline. In the code below, these traces were defined with the function `get_trace`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

colour_1 = "rgb(190, 226, 222)"
colour_2 = "rgb(27, 173, 172)"
colour_3 = "rgb(0, 93, 100)"

colourscale = [[0, colour_1],
               [0.2, colour_2],
               [1, colour_3]]

countries = ['BDI', 'BEN', 'BFA', 'BWA', 'CIV', 'CMR', 'COD', 'CPV', 'ETH', 'GHA', 'GIN', 'GMB', 'KEN', 'LBR', 'LSO', 'MDG', 'MLI', 'MOZ', 'MUS', 'MWI', 'NER', 'NGA', 'RWA', 'SEN', 'SLE', 'SOM', 'STP', 'TCD', 'TGO', 'TZA', 'UGA', 'ZAF', 'ZMB', 'ZWE']
z = [5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 14, 7, 1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 13, 1, 3, 11, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 50, 18, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 16, 15, 4, 10, 4]
counts = pd.Series(data=z, index=countries)
code_to_priority = {'MLI': 2, 'BWA': 0, 'CPV': 0, 'ZAF': 0, 'TGO': 1, 'COD': 2, 'KEN': 0, 'SSD': 2, 'CIV': 0, 'NGA': 1, 'MWI': 0, 'SOM': 0, 'MUS': 0, 'MRT': 2, 'ETH': 0, 'RWA': 1, 'TZA': 0, 'TCD': 2, 'MOZ': 2, 'LBR': 0, 'MDG': 1, 'GIN': 1, 'LSO': 0, 'BFA': 2, 'BDI': 0, 'SLE': 0, 'CMR': 0, 'SEN': 0, 'BEN': 0, 'GHA': 0, 'NER': 2, 'ZMB': 0, 'ZWE': 0, 'GMB': 0, 'STP': 0, 'UGA': 0}


def get_trace(priority):
    line_width = 2
    if priority == 0:
        outline_params = dict()  # no special outline
    elif priority == 1:
        outline_params = dict(marker=dict(line=dict(
            color='rgb(250, 86, 93)',
            width=line_width
        )))  # red outline
    else:
        outline_params = dict(marker=dict(line=dict(
            color='rgb(247, 150, 70)',
            width=line_width
        )))  # orange outline
    mask = counts.index.map(code_to_priority) == priority
    out = dict(
        type='choropleth',
        locations=list(counts[mask].index),
        locationmode='ISO-3',
        colorscale=colourscale,
        z=list(counts[mask]),
        zmin=0,
        zmax=counts.max())
    out.update(outline_params)
    return out


data_p0 = get_trace(0)
data_p1 = get_trace(1)
data_p2 = get_trace(2)
layout = dict(
    geo={'scope': 'africa'},
    title='Number of projects supported by the Help Desk, by country',
    title_x=0.5)

map = go.Figure(data=[data_p0, data_p2, data_p1], layout=layout)
py.plot(map)
```